# Openstack and neutron failing: Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, or access to an upstream git repository

Tags: python-3.x, devstack, openstack-neutron

I have already tried the Stack Overflow solution [58854822](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58854822/python-setup-py-sdist-error-versioning-for-this-project-requires-either-an-sdist) (`python setup.py sdist error Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, or access to an upstream git repository`).

The solution at https://www.roaet.com/uncategorized/problem-with-pbr-and-sdist-tarball/ also no longer works.

===

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.

Trying to install an ***all-in-one*** with ***a single network card*** using the instructions [here](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/guides/single-machine.html) and [here](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/guides/neutron.html). Openstack (devstack) installs and works fine if I do ***not*** include the lines in `local.conf` which use neutron (I.e. nothing below the `## Neutron options`  line ... but, of course, then it won't work with the single NIC.

The error I get is ...

```
Obtaining file:///opt/stack/keystone
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3.8 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/opt/stack/keystone/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/opt/stack/keystone/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info
         cwd: /opt/stack/keystone/
    Complete output (16 lines):
    Error parsing
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pbr/core.py", line 111, in pbr
        attrs = util.cfg_to_args(path, dist.script_args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pbr/util.py", line 272, in cfg_to_args
        pbr.hooks.setup_hook(config)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pbr/hooks/__init__.py", line 25, in setup_hook
        metadata_config.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pbr/hooks/base.py", line 27, in run
        self.hook()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pbr/hooks/metadata.py", line 25, in hook
        self.config['version'] = packaging.get_version(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pbr/packaging.py", line 872, in get_version
        raise Exception("Versioning for this project requires either an sdist"
    Exception: Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, or access to an upstream git repository. It's also possible that there is a mismatch between the package name in setup.cfg and the argument given to pbr.version.VersionInfo. Project name keystone was given, but was not able to be found.
    error in setup command: Error parsing /opt/stack/keystone/setup.cfg: Exception: Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, or access to an upstream git repository. It's also possible that there is a mismatch between the package name in setup.cfg and the argument given to pbr.version.VersionInfo. Project name keystone was given, but was not able to be found.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

My local.conf looks like...

```
HOST_IP=192.168.68.111
SERVICE_HOST=192.168.68.111
MYSQL_HOST=192.168.68.111
RABBIT_HOST=192.168.68.111
GLANCE_HOSTPORT=192.168.68.111:9292
ADMIN_PASSWORD=secret
DATABASE_PASSWORD=secret
RABBIT_PASSWORD=secret
SERVICE_PASSWORD=secret

## Neutron options
Q_USE_SECGROUP=True
FLOATING_RANGE="192.168.68.0/24"
IPV4_ADDRS_SAFE_TO_USE="10.0.0.0/22"
Q_FLOATING_ALLOCATION_POOL=start=192.168.68.250,end=192.168.68.254
PUBLIC_NETWORK_GATEWAY="192.168.68.1"
PUBLIC_INTERFACE=ens33

# Open vSwitch provider networking configuration
Q_USE_PROVIDERNET_FOR_PUBLIC=True
OVS_PHYSICAL_BRIDGE=br-ex
PUBLIC_BRIDGE=br-ex
OVS_BRIDGE_MAPPINGS=public:br-ex
```

I've even tried installing all the Python modules from the `/opt/stack/requirements/upper-constraints.txt` manually, but it makes no difference. I have also tried installing the Keystone repo separately, with the same error.